# Map array of objects to create nested ul depending on property

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I would like to arrange this data on a `ul` structure, nesting according to their `Rank`

```
const staff = [
  {
    Rank: 1,
    ID: '1',
    Role: 'Managing Director',
    Name: 'Peter'
  },
  {
    Rank: 2,
    ID: '2',
    Role: 'Operations Director',
    Name: 'Jane'
  },
  {
    Rank: 2,
    ID: '3',
    EmployeeImage: '',
    Role: 'Head of Client Services',
    Name: 'John',
  },
  {
    Rank: 3,
    ID: '4',
    EmployeeImage: '',
    Role: 'Senior Developer',
    Name: 'Tom',
  }
]
```

Desired output

```
<div>
  <h2>Managing Director</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h2>Operations Director</div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h2>Senior Developer</h2>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>Head of Client Services</h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Link to react codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-j9fco?file=/src/index.tsx)

I am trying to do lots of conditions with JSX but I am not getting anywhere and it's getting quite messy, is this approach in the right direction or are there better ways to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to make a tree-based structure mirroring the HTML you want. One option is to aim for something like

```
{
  people: ['Managing Director'],
  children: {
    people: ['Operations Director', 'Head of Client Services'],
    children: {
      people: ['Senior Developer']
    }
  }
}
```

which can be done with

```js
const staff = [
  {
    Rank: 1,
    ID: '1',
    Role: 'Managing Director',
    Name: 'Peter'
  },
  {
    Rank: 2,
    ID: '2',
    Role: 'Operations Director',
    Name: 'Jane'
  },
  {
    Rank: 2,
    ID: '3',
    EmployeeImage: '',
    Role: 'Head of Client Services',
    Name: 'John',
  },
  {
    Rank: 3,
    ID: '4',
    EmployeeImage: '',
    Role: 'Senior Developer',
    Name: 'Tom',
  }
];

const peopleByRank = {};
for (const { Rank, Role } of staff) {
  (peopleByRank[Rank] ??= []).push(Role);
}
const tree = Object.values(peopleByRank)
  .reduceRight((children, people) => ({ 
   children: children?.children ? children : { people: children },
   people }));
console.log(tree);
```

Then render it recursively:

```js
const tree = {
  people: ['Managing Director'],
  children: {
    people: ['Operations Director', 'Head of Client Services'],
    children: {
      people: ['Senior Developer']
    }
  }
};

const List = ({ data }) => (
  <ul>
    <li>
      {
        data.people.map(person => <div>{person}</div>)
      }
      {
        !data.children ? null : <li><List data={data.children} /></li>
      }
    </li>
  </ul>
);
const App = () => {
  return <List data={tree} />
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: Wow thanks, I am going to need to get my head around this and how to put it on TypeScript

Comment: Oops, you're right, need an extra `<li></li>` around the returned List

Comment: Still the `ul` should be inside its parent `li` not have its own `li`, that will make it a sibling of its 'parent'.

Comment: it's my fault I made the wrong structure. I have corrected the desired output.

Comment: So you just want a single `<li>` associated with each `<ul>`? You can do that, but if the purpose is just for nested indentation, you might find it more appropriate to do that with CSS and regular containers like `<div>`s with classes

Comment: To be honest I was really going after this: https://dzone.com/articles/css-flex-based-orgchart-with-zk, cause the css is quite simple

Comment: The code in that link has a separate `<li>` for each subitem, not a single `<li>` for each nesting level